# Not able to receive messages from JMS temporary queue

Tags: request, jms, reply

I have searched for the solution but couldn't make it work. Here is the summary. I am trying to implement a webservice which runs on Glassfish 2.1 that implements a synchronous JMS Request-Response using Temporary queue. It sends a message to another Glassfish application running on remote server. I am able to send the message and process it but when the final message is sent back to temporary queue, the webservice gets the response as null. Here is the code:

private Message requestReply(String msg, Queue jmsRequestResponse, ConnectionFactory jmsRequestRespConnFactory) {

```
    javax.jms.Connection conn = null;       
    javax.jms.MessageConsumer consumer = null;
    javax.jms.Message replyMsg = null;
    javax.jms.Session sess = null;       

    try {
        logger.debug("[requestreply input message[" + msg);
        conn = jmsRequestRespConnFactory.createConnection();
        conn.start();
        sess = conn.createSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        javax.jms.Message reqMessage = sess.createTextMessage(msg);
        javax.jms.Destination replyDestination = (jmsRequestResponse instanceof javax.jms.Queue) ? sess.createTemporaryQueue() : sess.createTemporaryTopic();

        reqMessage.setJMSReplyTo(replyDestination);
        sess.createProducer(jmsRequestResponse).send(reqMessage);                  

        replyMsg = consumer.receive(60000);            
        consumer.close();
        sess.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        logger.debug("exception in requestreply");
    } finally {
        if (consumer != null) {
            try {
                consumer.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }           
    }
    return replyMsg;
}
```

what am I missing here?? When I print the replyMsg, it is always null.

Comment: null msg means you did not get a reply. Are you sure you are sending the reply back correctly? The code only shows the caller side.

Comment: Yes. The application which is replying back is an existing application which is used by other applciation. Now I am trying to develop webservice and connect to the same application which process the message. In the reply back application, I see in the logs that it sent the processed message where it gets the data from database and sends back to temporary queue: [STCTemporary.8af7d0f70030432b947353fcd575e229.S75.425df6bf-90e9-4b79-84f9-a855904e818a] This the same temporary queue name when the message it got and processed it and sending back.

Comment: I found that the issue is with send of the message. Since I have set a timeout of 60secs, the temporary queue expires exactly at that time. What I see is that when I send the message to remote server, it takes near to 60 secs to send due to which when the response reaches the temporary queue it is already 60secs and it expires before the client gets the message from queue and hence reply is null. But I couldn't figure out when the send(msg) is taking that long to connect to remote server and send the message. Any help is appreciated.